# Pandas: whole column used as input modified

Tags: function, pandas

I have a little function performing a cumsum of nan values over a column in pandas. The function is a little bit tricky since I want a reset of values when switching from a nan to a non-nan cells.

Ex: [1., 1., nan, nan, 2., nan, nan, 3.] gives [0., 0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.]

Anyway the function is working and here it is:

```
def count_nan_reset(v):
vm = v.copy()
vm = v.as_matrix()
vm[~np.isnan(vm)] = 2 # arbitraire
vm[np.isnan(vm)] = 1
vm[vm==2] = np.nan
n = np.isnan(vm)
a = ~n
c = np.cumsum(a)
d = np.diff(np.concatenate(([0.], c[n])))
vm[n] = -d
fin = np.cumsum(vm)
return fin
```

The issue I have is that when I try to apply this function to a column as input, it changes the columns itself (as an inplace = True option would do)!!

For instance:

```
d = {'Values_for_trial' : pd.Series([1., 1., np.nan, np.nan, 2., np.nan, np.nan, 3.])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df["results"] = count_nan_reset(df["Values_for_trial"])
```

Well it changes the values inside df["Values_for_trial"]

I do not really know why if anyone can help thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because vm is not a copy,

You need to change

```
def count_nan_reset(v):
    vm = v.copy()
    vm = v.as_matrix()
```

To

```
def count_nan_reset(v):
    vm = v.copy().as_matrix()
    ...
```

Comment: Wow this thing drove me insane thank you so much it works! :)